Removing "hidden" network interfaces in Windows 11
Using netsh, I see some "hidden" network interfaces:
number 13: "Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 1"
number 7: "Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 2"

probably inherited from a previous upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11.
These interfaces do not appear in the interface list in the Control Panel and they seem to create some incompatibility with VPN software Netbird.
How can I remove them? I tried deleting them in the registry, wherever I found their names with a search, but they appeared again.
netsh int ipv4 show interfaces

Idx     Met.         MTU          Stato                Nome
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 91           5       65535  disconnected  Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)
  4          50        1500  connected     Wi-Fi
 29           5        1500  disconnected  Ethernet
 16          25        1500  disconnected  OpenVPN TAP
 13          25        1500  disconnected  Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 1
 10          65        1500  disconnected  Connessione di rete Bluetooth
  7          25        1500  disconnected  Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 2
 26          35        1500  disconnected  Ethernet 2
 14          35        1500  connected     VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
 22          35        1500  connected     VMware Network Adapter VMnet8

EDIT:
The incompatibility I get with Netbird is that Netbird continuously restarts due to one of those network interfaces, when I'm in Wifi (it doesn't happen if I'm connected with the ethernet cable). These are the relevant lines in Netbird logs:
2024-07-31T21:30:40+02:00 INFO client/internal/networkmonitor/monitor_windows.go:159: network monitor: default route for 192.168.0.1 (Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 1) is gone or changed
2024-07-31T21:30:41+02:00 INFO client/internal/engine.go:1520: Network monitor detected network change, restarting engine

EDIT 2:
I gave details about Netbird because I was asked to clarify, but actually, I don't think it's a problem with Netbird (client version 0.28.6). I would just like to know how I can delete those 2 old network interfaces, which have no reason to be there and also don't appear in the Control Panel. Netbird somehow happens to find an invalid route to the WiFi default gateway (192.168.0.1) through one of those two networks and restarts every 30 seconds. I think that the problem should be solved, if I can remove those invalid interfaces completely.

Can you give us more information about the issue you believe they may be creating with your VPN?

@music2myear I edited the question to explain the problem with Netbird VPN

This question should include more details and clarify the problem. These details must be in English.

continuously restarts how often? What version of the netbird client do you have?

I tried to clarify in EDIT 2

When you look at network connections, can you delete them there?

@music2myear no, they don't appear among network connections in the control panel. I tried to search for them in the Windows registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\ and other places I found with a search) and delete them there, but they appeared again

Generally, do not delete or add things directly in your registry. The registry records ("registers") values, it is not usually the right or best place to make changes. So, you've already found this to be useless, but going forward, don't delete things in your registry. You need to find the right place to delete these and THAT action will then be stored in the registry after it is done correctly.


Open Device Manager as a local administrator.
Find and expand the Network adapters section.
In the toolbar, open the View menu and click Show hidden devices.
Find the invalid/bad entries in the list of Network Adapters, and for each of these in turn right-click and then select Uninstall device.

Once you've completed this, restart your computer and try again.

This is generally a good suggestion and I had already tried it, but unfortunately they do not even appear there (no hidden device appears among network adapters when I choose "Show hidden devices"). It's a mystery... In the end I did a quick and dirty thing, i.e. I patched Netbird source code to ignore "Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 1" and "2" adapters, then recompiled it, but of course I didn't really solve the cause of problem. I only solved one of the effects: the one I actually cared about.

That sounds like a good solution to me.
